# Can HIVE UDF communicate outside of its shell

Tags: hive

I have a HIVE GenericUDF that decrypts the social security. It takes the ssn column validates the input and decrypts whenever the function is called.

Is there a way for this GenericUDF in the initialize method to talk to hbase or other hive tables that has the list of valid users and validate if the incoming user that had requested the decrypt UDF is actually authorized to perform this action.

Any other ideas to achieve this is also appreciated..My intention is to validate the user requesting to perform the decrypt function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the 'distributed_map' and hbase_cached_get UDF's from Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ).  If the table is small enough you can send it to all nodes via distributed cache, and then pass that map into your UDF as an argument.  If the table is too large, you can store it in HBase, and use hbase_get or hbase_cached_get to do your lookups, and use IF logic accordingly.  If there are some values which are commonly repeated, use the hbase_cached_get to avoid extra lookups; otherwise just use hbase_get

A more detailed discussion of a similar use-case is described in the blog posting http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/squash-the-long-tail-with-brickhouses-hbase-udfs/

Comment: Will you be able to help me on this?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737546/error-while-calling-hive-generic-udf